# simple html 5 canvas not working

Tags: html, visual-studio

Why wont this work in my firefox when I run it from visualstudio 2012 express. it works in jsfiddle.net

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
      <title></title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(100, 150);
        context.lineTo(450, 50);
        context.stroke();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: works fine in FF19.0.2 here. check your JS error console and whatnot?

Comment: in VS2012 menu File - Browse with - Firefox, works fine, just tested in FF 15.0.1 and 19.0.2; notice that VS launch ASP.NET Development server to serve the page to FF

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me in Firefox 18.0.1.
Did you try to open just the HTML file directly? Just to check if the problem it's with your browser or with your visualstudio?

Also check if JS is enabled in Firefox:

Enabling and disabling JavaScript

In Firefox, you can configure whether JavaScript in web pages is permitted to execute or not. To allow JavaScript in Firefox:

> - At the top of the Firefox window, click on the Firefox button and then select Options
> - In the Options window, select the Content panel.
> - Enable JavaScript: Select this option to permit JavaScripts to execute on your computer.
> - To change advanced settings, click Advanced....
> - Click OK to close the Options window

@MarcB Questioned about JS errors. Is there any?